# Cleanest way to write if with multiple else with condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, ecmascript-6

I am writing a conditional if else. There's multiple else statements. What is the cleanest way to write it? And the best way to code it down.

PS I am new to reactJS.

```
if (type === activity.fetchPeople && loading) {
    await store.dispatch(fetchPeople(store, 20, 0, params.sectionType));
    store.dispatch(showGlobalLoader(false));
  } else if (type === activity.pathfallRevert) {
    await store.dispatch(fetchactivityfallRevert(store, params.userId, 20, 0));
    activityPro = `${labels.pathfallRevert} (${params.count})`;
    store.dispatch(showGlobalLoader(false));
  } else if (type === activity.pathfall) {
    await store.dispatch(fetchactivityfall(store, params.userId, 20, 0));
    activityPro = `${labels.pathfall} (${params.count})`;
    store.dispatch(showGlobalLoader(false));
  } else if (type === activity.road) {
    await store.dispatch(fetchRoads(store, params.userId, 20, 0));
    activityPro = `${labels.road} (${params.count})`;
    store.dispatch(showGlobalLoader(false));
  } else if (type === activity.movers) {
    await store.dispatch(fetchmovers(store, params.userId, 20, 0));
    activityPro = `${labels.movers} (${params.count})`;
    store.dispatch(showGlobalLoader(false));
  } else {
    store.dispatch(showGlobalLoader(false));
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: you can use the switch case for the same

Comment: In such situations, I usually use a dictionary/map (in JS it'd just be an object). For example, you can do something like: `activityPro = {fetchPeople: null, pathfallRevert: ${labels.pathfallRevert} (${params.count}, /* remaining if-branches */}[type]`, then do similar for args of `store.dispatch`, and call the function at the end with the appropriate args selected from indexing the object.

Answer (score 1):

you may use Switch\Case

```js
switch(type) {
  case activity.fetchPeople:
    // code block
    break;
  case activity.pathfallRevert:
    // code block
    break;
  default:
    store.dispatch(showGlobalLoader(false));
    // code block
  }
```

Comment: see  the first `if (type === activity.fetchPeople && loading)`

Comment: You could then add an if into the first case. I agree that the cleanest way to do this is a switch.
`case activity.fetchPeople:
    if(loading) {
        doSomething();
        break;
    } else {
        break;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

We get really used to the if/else syntax, especially if we are coming from other object oriented languages. For me it was Java, and this pattern was hard to deviate from when learning the fundamentals of Javascript. As a general rule, if you see a lot of if/else if/else (especially if the conditional statement is similar in each one), then something can probably be done differently.

As someone else noted, the switch/case syntax is intended for exactly this use case. It is clean and readable, and it makes it easy to understand and add to later.

Another (more advanced) option would be to use Javascript's Object literals. In this case, you have each different `type` resulting in a different action. You could have an Object that looks something like:

```
var activities = {
  'activity.fetchPeople': function() {
    if (loading) {
      await store.dispatch(fetchPeople(store, 20, 0, params.sectionType))
      store.dispatch(showGlobalLoader(false))
    }
  },
  'activity.pathfallRevert': function() {
    await store.dispatch(...);
    activityPro = `${labels.pathfallRevert} (${params.count})`;
    store.dispatch(showGlobalLoader(false));
  }
}
```

After building this out for all of your activity types, you can call `activities[type]()`

Comment: I use it in React component. I do not call this. If I do what I need to pass in the type?

Comment: Also one more thing. I want async function. Could I use arrow function?

Comment: Get this error `activities[type] is not a function`